# Error al conectarse a la base de datos .NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net

he creado una aplicación web que consta de 4 páginas, resulta que 3 de ellas no necesitan conectarse a la base de datos pero una si y cuando quiero mostrar dicha página me Salta este error

> "Win32Exception (0x80004005): The user name or password is incorrect".

He cambiado la BD a la local y lo hace sin problemas, el tema es cuando quiero conectarme a la que esta en el servidor, estoy más que seguro que el usuario y la contraseña están bien porque los revise mil veces y no encuentro errores. Probé con cambiar la base de datos del `web.config` y sigue igual

Comment: El error dice que el "user o password que envias es incorrrecto", asi que deberiamos verificar eso primero. 1) cual DB es? puede aclarar (MS SQL Server?) 2) Prueba conectarte con dicho usuario/pass con la herramienta de administracion de la db. Puedes? 3) Seria bueno ver la cadena de conexion como la armas para verificar (oculta los datos sensibles, pero que sea la cadena completa)

Comment: La base de datos es MS SQL Server, puedo conectarme sin problemas desde Management Studio 18 sin problemas, esta es la cadena de conexión: " strconexion = "Data Source=SQL5080.site4now.net;Initial Catalog=DB_A68458_Ateo19;User Id=DB_A68458_Ateo19_admin;Password=*******; "

Comment: O sea desde el Management Studio puedes acceder con el usuario "DB_A68458_Ateo19_admin"? Bueno si la respuesta es SI

Comment: Exacto, es mas ya tengo las tablas correspondientes creadas, y puedo realizar las consultas que desee. Si yo ejecuto la pagina desde el Visual Studio, esta anda sin problemas no importa cual sea la base de datos (Local o del Servidor), el problema aparede cuando quiero ingresar desde la url que me da el servidor

Comment: entonces vamos al codigo.. puedes colocar por favor en tu pregunta parte de tu codigo como creas la conexion a la DB? y que clases/objetos utilizas para conectarte (Sqlconnection, SQlCommand, etc) o sea parte del codigo que es el que te da error. O si puedes mucho mejor seria que dejes un repositorio publico (por ejemplo en GitHub como para descargar y verificar, o sea armar una demo sencilla). Todo esto para ayudarte mejor

Comment: Ya lo pude arreglar, solo elimine todos los archivos del servidor y los volví a subir